# STM32 Black Pill cannot detect i2c slaves

Tags: stm32, i2c, arduino-ide

Im running the Arduino Wire scanner example on an STM32 F411 black pill but it refuses to find devices. I have double checked my pins PB7(sda) PB6(scl).
Disconnecting i2c pins does not cause program to hang so i am assuming there are internal pull-up resistors.
The same example works perfectly on an arduino pro mini.
What am I missing?

```
// i2c_scanner
//
// Version 1
//    This program (or code that looks like it)
//    can be found in many places.
//    For example on the Arduino.cc forum.
//    The original author is not know.
// Version 2, Juni 2012, Using Arduino 1.0.1
//     Adapted to be as simple as possible by Arduino.cc user Krodal
// Version 3, Feb 26  2013
//    V3 by louarnold
// Version 4, March 3, 2013, Using Arduino 1.0.3
//    by Arduino.cc user Krodal.
//    Changes by louarnold removed.
//    Scanning addresses changed from 0...127 to 1...119,
//    according to the i2c scanner by Nick Gammon
//    http://www.gammon.com.au/forum/?id=10896
// Version 5, March 28, 2013
//    As version 4, but address scans now to 127.
//    A sensor seems to use address 120.
//
// This sketch tests the standard 7-bit addresses
// Devices with higher bit address might not be seen properly.
//



/* Example pinmap for Bluepill I2Cs (by Testato)

 I2C-1 standard pins: PB7(sda) PB6(scl)
 Use it by "Wire" without pin declaration
  Wire.begin();

 I2C-1 alternative pins: PB9(sda) PB8(scl)
 Remap the first I2C before call begin()
  Wire.setSDA(PB9);
  Wire.setSCL(PB8);
  Wire.begin();

 I2C-2: PB11(sda) PB10(scl)
 Remap the second I2C before call begin()
  Wire.setSDA(PB11);
  Wire.setSCL(PB10);
  Wire.begin();

 If you want to use the two I2Cs simultaneously, create a new instance for the second I2C
  TwoWire Wire2(PB11,PB10);
  Wire2.begin();
 
*/


#include <Wire.h>


void setup() {

  Serial.begin(115200);
  Wire.begin();
  Serial.println("\nI2C Scanner");
}


void loop() {
  byte error, address;
  int nDevices;

  Serial.println("Scanning...");

  nDevices = 0;
  for(address = 1; address < 127; address++) {
    // The i2c_scanner uses the return value of
    // the Write.endTransmisstion to see if
    // a device did acknowledge to the address.

    Wire.beginTransmission(address);
    error = Wire.endTransmission();
    
    if (error == 0) {
      Serial.print("I2C device found at address 0x");
      if (address < 16) 
        Serial.print("0");
      Serial.println(address, HEX);

      nDevices++;
    }
    else if (error == 4) {
      Serial.print("Unknown error at address 0x");
      if (address < 16) 
        Serial.print("0");
      Serial.println(address, HEX);
    }    
  }
  if (nDevices == 0)
    Serial.println("No I2C devices found");
  else
    Serial.println("done");

  delay(5000);           // wait 5 seconds for next scan
}
```

**Update:**

Im trying to communicate with an es9038.
I have been using an arduino pro mini for this but wanted to switch to stm32.

I2C between arduino and blackpill works.

Blackpill to es9038 does not.

I have tried adding 4k7 pull-up resistors to both sda and scl.

Comment: `so i am assuming there are internal pull-up resistors` do not assume it

Comment: Do you have external resistors? Is pull-up activated? Does the slave device work at this MCU's voltage? Some Arduino boards (most) are 5V, and 5V peripheral may not work with 3.3V signal. Please, give more details about hardware configuration.

Comment: Yes I have added 4k7 pull-upp resistors to sda and scl.
Both devices are 3.3v.